# is/can the probabilistic nature of quantum mechanics be explained by general relativity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, general-relativity, speed-of-light, probability, causality

It seems that as you drop down to smaller and smaller distances-scales you'd have greater and greater relative discrepancies of occurrences in the universe when you consider everything to be relative.

Can these discrepancies explain, if not produce the weird probabilistic phenomenon at the quantum realm? If not what don't I understand? Why is this intuition wrong?

EDIT: To try to be more clear allow me to introduce an analogy.

If you're familiar with blockchain technology you'll know that each computer can be thought of as a node in the network. They share messages back and forth in a broadcast manner. Sometimes a computer will get a message that others don't, and if it wins the race to determine the consensus of what has happened in the most recent past the other computers will adopt its view of the history of the network. In other words, the longest coherent chain wins.

Applying this analogy to an elementary view of quantum physics we could see a computer as a particle, or point, messages between them as forces between particles and consensus as the coherence of matter and energy on a macro scale.

In the blockchain network, a computer gets messages A, B, C in that order, but another computer gets the messages in the B, C, A order. Eventually, they will agree when they adopt the longer chain, (the larger the spacetime) and all will arrive at a consensus.

Is this what is happening at the quantum scale? from one particle's point of view traveling at a high speed in a certain direction sees the universe, especially his local universe in a very particular order whereas other particle's points of view disagree with his as they travel in a different direction at a high rate of speed? Could those "discrepancies in views of the universe" (the order in which every particle feels forces) create the probabilistic nature of the quantum world?

Comment: "When you consider everything to be relative" is too broad a statement to be useful. Can you state explicitly what you mean by that?

Comment: Also, what do you mean by "discrepancies of occurrences"?

Comment: yes, I'll add more to the question.

Comment: *"Why is this intuition wrong?"* - What you've written is essentially gibberish.  Voting to close.

Comment: hold on now Alfred Centauri, help me understand, then I'll close it myself if you like.

Comment: This is a very interesting way of attempting to link cryptography and QM. Unfortunately, assuming that individual particles see events in a certain order smacks of a hidden-variable theory to me (where the hidden variable is the order of events the particle saw), and hidden-variable theories have been proven wrong by violation of Bell's inequality.

Comment: @probably_someone, no, only local hidden variable theories have been disproved, non-local ones are well and healthy

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams Oops, sorry, forgot about that.

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams Of course, I'd say non-local variables and GR have a love/hate relationship... but I'd say it's pretty much hate/hate across the board.

Comment: @probably_someone yes, I know that most people chose a local random theory vs a non-local deterministic one. I guess the fad might change in the future.

Comment: If I may hazard a guess as to where Alfred is coming from, using your apparent Computer-Science background, it looks like "To me as a layman, symmetric cryptography like AES and 3d graphics look really similar.  Has anyone ever thought to explain 3d rendering using symmetric cryptography?"  It's far enough out in left field that it's hard to really make a start at answering it.  The first step would be figuring out why you find them similar when nobody else does, and then addressing that disconnect.  Easier done in person than on SE, in my opinion.

Comment: @CortAmmon I know there are Lorentz invariant upgraded versions of the debrogile bohm, even some that look QTF-like, but I am not an expert. I did not hear about GR compatible ones, do you know any reference that discuss their difficulty in integrating them with GR?

Comment: @WillyBillyWilliams I'm thinking more from the "explaining QM with GR" approach, GR is going to have trouble explaining how non-local variables appear to propagate faster than light.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no evidence at all to suggest that quantum mechanics supervenes on general relativity.  General relativity, on a small scale, predicts none of the effects that we see in quantum mechanics.  If it did, we wouldn't need quantum mechanics.  There's nothing probabilistic about GR, nor does GR form any of the structures that arise in QM, nor does GR have anything to say about "spooky action at a distance."

It does, however, provide an interesting take on [magnetism](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1TKSfAkWWN0).

Comment: Thank you for your answer Cort, but does it not predict different "view's" of the universe according to a body's speed? Why is it (not your words) "gibberish" for those alternative points of view to produce a probabilistic universe? This is an honest question, from my layman point of view they look alike.

Comment: From a layman's perspective, it's probably best to rely on an appeal to authority.  Currently one of the great unsolved questions in physics is how to unify GR and QM.  Nobody knows how to do it.  If QM supervened on GR, someone would have noticed by now.

Comment: I do appeal to authority: I'll believe whatever you tell me! But I still don't understand _why_ this is bad intuition. I thought it must be a question pervasive among 1st-year theoretical physicists so I expected a quick and well-rehearsed answer. But I'm not getting that. So now I wonder if its a matter of patience? Given enough time _could_ you go through the basics and explain where my intuition goes wrong? Or is this a new idea to you that is just such a weird question that you don't know how to answer it? or is it literally a question without an answer, like "what color is 7?"

Comment: Well, the first thing I'd do if I was putting forward such a theory that the two disciplines are combined would be to pick a single facet of QM and demonstrate that it can be explained via GR.  From there, I could then see whether it looks like that approach is going to work for explaining all of QM.  In this case, I'm having trouble picking anything in QM that I think would be easily modeled via GR, so its a tricky one to start on.

Comment: One thing which got mentioned in the comments, which may be very helpful for seeing the challenges in your approach is the [Bell Inequalities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bell%27s_theorem).  They're a set of inequalities which seem inviolate using classical approaches (such as GR), but which it is easy to show that QM violates.  It doesn't prove that QM doesn't supervene on GR, but it does put a major hurdle in the way.

Comment: +1 for" supervenes". had to look it up in webster ! seems to be to opposite of "emerges"